# Call a page function from usercontrol code

Tags: c#, wpf, function, class

I'm developing a C# and WPF app.
I have a WPF Page 'HomeView' with a UserControl 'CreateItem'. After I click a Button (which related function is `Close()`) inside the UserControl, I have to make the UserControl visibility collapsed and call a function 'ReloadAnalytics' in the Page code.

```
namespace iMP
{
    public partial class CreateItem : UserControl
    {

    public CreateItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HomeView objHomeView= new HomeView();
        objHomeView.CreateNewItemDisplayGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        objHomeView.InitializeAnalyticsOverview();
    }
}
```

When I call this function, pressing the Button, nothing happens. (`CreateNewItemDisplayGrid` is the name of the UserControl in `HomeView`)
(`HomeView` namespace is `iMP.Views` and the public partial class is `HomeView : Page`)

Comment: From what I understand, I think you need to invoke an event from the `CreateItem` usercontrol and then subscribe to this event in your `HomeView` page, which actually executes the code that is now in `Close()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the structure below. I defined an event in `usercontrol` and use that event in the main form.

**Try to match the code with your code**

**In UserControl**

```
public partial class CreateItem : UserControl
{
    public event ClickEventHandler CloseButtonClick;
    public delegate void ClickEventHandler(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
    public CreateItem()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (CloseButtonClick != null)
       {
           CloseButtonClick(this, e);
       }
    }
}
```

**In HomeView**

```html
public partial class HomeView : Page
{
   public HomeView()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      CreateItem userControl = new CreateItem();
      this.Content = userControl;
      userControl.CloseButtonClick += UserControl_CloseButtonClick;
   }

   private void UserControl_CloseButtonClick(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       ///...................................
       this.CreateNewItemDisplayGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
       ///.......................
   }
}
```